# Camera does not return to OnActivityResult

Tags: android, camera

Hi first of all i know this question already has been asked but i am stuck on it more than one day  i want to take a picture with camera intent and save it on `ExternalStoragePublicDirectory` of phone but after taking the picture it doesn't return to `OnActivityResult` nor the picture is saved. it's not working in android 6 and 7:
any help would be appericiated!!

```
Uri imageUri = setImageUri();
Intent intent1 = new 
Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

intent1.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = 
MedicalActivity.this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent1, 
PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
String packageName =resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName; 


MainActivity.this.grantUriPermission(packageName, imageUri, 
Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | 
Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
}

startActivityForResult(intent1, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
```

set image Uri:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "myappimages");
if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {mediaStorageDir.mkdir();}
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File file;
        file = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");


        Uri imgUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MedicalActivity.this,
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                file);

        return imgUri;

    }
```

File provider path:

```
<external-path name="myapp_images_path" path="Pictures/myappimages"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

from android version greater than 6 and equal to 6 you need to request for permission of storage and camera
for example check this link https://androidkennel.org/android-camera-access-tutorial/ and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Yes i add that too. i request for 'Manifest.permission.CAMERA' and 'Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' and start camera intent from 'onRequestPermissionsResult' but i still have the same issue!